# Jenkins not able to find out pom.xml

Tags: jenkins

I created a project and pushed it in the git.Once I configured it in Jenkins using JDK 7 and Maven 3.0. Now when I try to build it using Jenkins it throws me an error like below.

> ERROR: No such file
>   /Users/ios/jenkins/workspace/ACADEM-4705-Test-Jenkins-Allegretto/pom.xml

Note: I am pushing the project as a whole into git

Answer (score 0):

where did your pom file exists in workspace ?

If your pom.xml file exists in the root folder of workspace , then there is no need for you to mention the path of pom.xml file. in Maven 3 step , leave it empty.

If your pom.xml file exists inside the root folder , then the easy way to access that would be

```
$workspace/subfolder/pom.xml
```

Please note you will commonly face this issue when "/" is provided in stead of "\" in different OS (windows,linux) or vice versa.